# Error:Vuser failed to initialize java_int.dll (Vugen/Loadrunner)

Tags: java, testing, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have been trying to execute a script in Vugen based on JAVA protocol, but everry time I want to replay it I get the following errors:

*Error:Vuser failed to initialize java_int.dll
Warning: Extension java_int.dll reports error -1 on call to function ExtPerThreadInitialize*

I already checked my JAVA variables, but I am not sure where else to look/ what else to modify.
Any suggestion?

I already checked the java compatibility with my LR version